# Unique orthogonal component of a vector with respect to a set of vectors

Tags: math, linear-algebra

I would like to obtain the orthogonal component of a vector **v** with respect to a set of vectors {**u_1**, **u_2**, ... **u_N**}. I can do this via a Gram-Schmidt style approach:

```
v_orth = v
for i=1:N
   v_orth = v_orth - proj(v_orth, u_i)

return v_orth/norm(v_orth)
```

However, the output of this algorithm is dependent on the order of the **u_i**. Is there a method that is independent of the order of the **u_i**? For example, one that returns the unique **v_orth** with minimal deviation from **v**?

Comment: Are the vectors u_i orthogonal to each other?

Comment: No, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure won't necessarily produce a vector that is orthogonal to all the us.

For example if there were just 2 us and the us weren't orthogonal. Then after the first step you will have a vector orthogonal to u1, but then the second step will (unless by chance the vector is already orthogonal to u2) subtract a multiple of u2 from the vector, and since u1.u2 != 0, the result will no longer be orthogonal to u1.

You need to first find a set of vectors w_1..w_M say (eg by modified Gram-Schmidt) that are orthogonal and span the same space as the us. Them  if you use your procedure with the ws instead of the us you will compute a vector that is orthogonal to all the ws, and hence to all the us. Moreover (rounding errors apart) this will not depend on the order of the vs.